# Convert 'a list to a Set?

Tags: ocaml

Is it really true that OCaml doesn't have a function which converts from a list to a set?

If that is the case, is it possible to make a generic function `list_to_set`? I've tried to make a polymorphic set without luck.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fundamental problem: Lists can contain elements of any types. Sets (assuming you mean the [Set](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.html) module of the standard library), in contrary, rely on a element comparison operation to remain balanced trees. You cannot hope to convert a `t list` to a set if you don't have a comparison operation on `t`.

Practical problem: the `Set` module of the standard library is functorized: it takes as input a *module* representing your element type and its comparison operation, and produces as output a *module* representing the set. Making this work with the simple parametric polymoprhism of lists is a bit sport.

To do this, the easiest way is to wrap your set_of_list function in a functor, so that it is itself parametrized by a comparison function.

```
module SetOfList (E : Set.OrderedType) = struct
  module S = Set.Make(E)
  let set_of_list li =
    List.fold_left (fun set elem -> S.add elem set) S.empty li
end
```

You can then use for example with the String module, which provides a suitable `compare` function.

```
  module SoL = SetOfList(String);;
  SoL.S.cardinal (SoL.set_of_list ["foo"; "bar"; "baz"]);; (* returns 3 *)
```

It is also possible to use different implementation of sets which are non-functorized, such as Batteries and Extlib 'PSet' implementation ([documentation](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/BatSet.html#6_Polymorphicsets)). The functorized design is advised because it has better typing guarantees -- you can't mix sets of the same element type using different comparison operations.

NB: of course, if you *already* have a given set module, instantiated form the Set.Make functor, you don't need all this; but you conversion function won't be polymorphic. For example assume I have the `StringSet` module defined in my code:

```
module StringSet = Set.Make(String)
```

Then I can write `stringset_of_list` easily, using `StringSet.add` and `StringSet.empty`:

```
let stringset_of_list li =
  List.fold_left (fun set elem -> StringSet.add elem set) StringSet.empty li
```

In case you're not familiar with folds, here is a direct, non tail-recursive recursive version:

```
let rec stringset_of_list = function
  | [] -> StringSet.empty
  | hd::tl -> StringSet.add hd (stringset_of_list tl)
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation :) I guess the generics in F# is somewhat easier to use in this specific example.

Comment: 'd rather have a right fold to add elements to a set, if only for the parameter order: `let stringset_of_list li = List.fold_right StringSet.add li StringSet.empty`

Comment: Note: as of OCaml 4.02 `Set.S` does contain [`of_list`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Set.S.html#VALof_list).

Answer (score 11):

Ocaml 3.12 has extensions ([7,13 Explicit naming of type variables](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/distrib/ocaml-3.12/ocaml-3.12-refman.html#htoc108) and [7,14 First-class modules](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/distrib/ocaml-3.12/ocaml-3.12-refman.html#htoc108)) that make it possible to instantiate and pass around modules for polymorphic values.

In this example, the `make_set` function returns a `Set` module for a given comparison function and the `build_demo` function constructs a set given a module and a list of values:

```
let make_set (type a) compare =
  let module Ord = struct
    type t = a
    let compare = compare
  end
  in (module Set.Make (Ord) : Set.S with type elt = a)

let build_demo (type a) set_module xs =
  let module S = (val set_module : Set.S with type elt = a) in
  let set = List.fold_right S.add xs S.empty in
    Printf.printf "%b\n" (S.cardinal set = List.length xs)

let demo (type a) xs = build_demo (make_set compare) xs

let _ = begin demo ['a', 'b', 'c']; demo [1, 2, 3]; end
```

This doesn't fully solve the problem, though, because the compiler doesn't allow the return value to have a type that depends on the module argument:

```
let list_to_set (type a) set_module xs =
  let module S = (val set_module : Set.S with type elt = a) in
    List.fold_right S.add xs S.empty

Error: This `let module' expression has type S.t
In this type, the locally bound module name S escapes its scope
```

A possible work-around is to return a collection of functions that operate on the hidden set value:

```
let list_to_add_mem_set (type a) set_module xs =
  let module S = (val set_module : Set.S with type elt = a) in
  let set = ref (List.fold_right S.add xs S.empty) in
  let add x = set := S.add x !set in
  let mem x = S.mem x !set in
    (add, mem)
```

Comment: Thank you :) I'm not garanteed to have OCaml 3.12 because I'm doing a compiler at my university. As mentioned above, I'll stick to make list_to_set for specific sets.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind a very crude approach, you can use the polymorphic hash table interface.  A hash table with an element type of unit is just a set.

```
# let set_of_list l = 
      let res = Hashtbl.create (List.length l)
      in let () = List.iter (fun x -> Hashtbl.add res x ()) l
      in res;;
val set_of_list : 'a list -> ('a, unit) Hashtbl.t = <fun>
# let a = set_of_list [3;5;7];;
val a : (int, unit) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
# let b = set_of_list ["yes";"no"];;
val b : (string, unit) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
# Hashtbl.mem a 5;;
- : bool = true
# Hashtbl.mem a 6;;
- : bool = false
# Hashtbl.mem b "no";;
- : bool = true
```

If you just need to test membership, this might be good enough.  If you wanted other set operations (like union and intersection) this isn't a very nice solution.  And it's definitely not very elegant from a typing standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Just extend the original type, as shown in
http://www.ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/benefits/modules.html
for the List module:

```
module StringSet = Set.Make (* define basic type *)
  (struct
     type t = string
     let compare = Pervasives.compare
   end)
module StringSet = struct (* extend type with more operations *)
  include StringSet
  let of_list l =
    List.fold_left
      (fun s e -> StringSet.add e s)
      StringSet.empty l
end;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the core library you could do something like:

```
let list_to_set l = 
List.fold l ~init:(Set.empty ~comparator:Comparator.Poly.comparator)
~f:Set.add |> Set.to_list
```

So for example:

```
list_to_set [4;6;3;6;3;4;3;8;2]
-> [2; 3; 4; 6; 8]
```

Or:

```
list_to_set ["d";"g";"d";"a"]
-> ["a"; "d"; "g"]
```